# SQL query - select row basing on the joined table's criteria

Tags: sql

I'm stuck within this simple scenario:

tableA

```
| ID | TableB_ID | Name |
```

tableA 1 ---> * tableB

tableB

```
| ID | Status_ID |
```

and I need to retrieve the `Name` column values from the `tableA`, whose contains rows in the `tableB` with Status_ID = 1 and Status_ID = 2 (two separate rows, it can be more with other values but it doesn't matter here)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.NAME
    FROM TABLE_A AS A INNER JOIN TABLE_B AS B ON A.TABLEB_ID = B.ID
    WHERE B.STATUS_ID IN (1, 2) -- OR OTHER VALUES
```

Comment: oh my... so simple. It obviously works, tkanks. I was rather playing with exists, having etc, that's why I was confused